# An example of a totally computable function that is not definable in system T?

Tags: computability, lo.logic, type-theory

Could you give me an example of a totally computable function of type N × N → N that is not definable in System T? Thanks.

Comment: I think this needs to be edited. "nat ⨯ nat → nat" does not make sense. Did you mean $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interpreters for T are not definable in T, thanks to the incompleteness theorem.

Concretely, fix a Godel encoding, and then let $f$ be the function which takes a pair consisting of a Godel-encoding of a closed term of type $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, and a natural number in $\mathbb{N}$, and returns the value of the application. This function is not definable in T. It's a worthwhile exercise to work out how you can use a self-interpreter to define an infinitely looping program.

Answer (score 8):

This just appeared on arxive.org and may be of some help.

> [*The definability of functionals in Gödel's theory T*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.6353)
>
> Matthew P. Szudzik (Carnegie Mellon)
>
> Gödel's theory T can be understood as a theory of the simply-typed lambda calculus that is extended to include the constant 0, the successor function $S$, and the operator $R_\tau$ for primitive recursion on objects of type $\tau$. It is known that the functions from non-negative integers to non-negative integers that can be defined in this theory are exactly the $\epsilon$-recursive functions of non-negative integers. But it is not well-known which functionals of arbitrary type can be defined in T.
>   We show that when the domain and codomain are restricted to pure closed normal forms, the functionals of arbitrary type that are definable in T are exactly those functionals that can be encoded as $\epsilon$-recursive functions of non-negative integers. This result has many interesting consequences, including a new characterization of T.